# c++ Destructor for Member Variables?

Tags: c++, class, object, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461064/are-member-variables-of-an-object-that-is-on-the-heap-also-automatically-on-the) post and I wanted to clarify, do I need to explicitly delete member variables of an object that has been created dynamically?

For example, I have a class with with two member variables,

```
class pointCloud
{
public:
    pointCloud();
    void addPoint(int);
    point getPoint(int);

private:
    int id;
    std::vector<point> pointArray;

};
```

and then I create a dynamic instance of it in main...

```
int main()
{

    pointCloud* cloud = new pointCloud;
    cloud->addPoint(8);

    delete cloud;
}
```

My understanding is that when `delete cloud;` is called, the 'id' and 'pointArray' variables will automatically be deleted/freed from memory. Is this correct? Or will I need to write a destructor to explicitly delete those member variables?

Comment: yes, right.. destructor is need for freeing dynamically allocated memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or will I need to write a destructor to explicitly delete those member variables?

In your case no need to write, because `id` is a primitive type, `pointArray` is a vector which already has destructor which will free memory.

But, if you use raw pointers (allocate buffer via new[]), then in the destructor you have to manually free memory (delete[]).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to delete the member variables - but you need to `delete` the content of the pointArray, if you created it (with `new`)

Generally, whatever *you* create (somewhere) with `new`, *you* need to `delete` also (somewhere); it is your problem to get that sorted out.
Here: you created pointCloud, and you deleted it. That's just fine.